# 建立urdf时，节点type="fixed"显示正常，type="continuous"异常

Tags: rviz, urdf

urdf在这里

```xml
> <!-- 
    需求: 创建机器人模型，底盘为长方体，
         在长方体的前面添加一摄像头，
         摄像头可以沿着 Z 轴 360 度旋转

 -->
 <robot name="mycar">
    <!-- 底盘 -->
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.5 0.2 0.1" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="blue">
                <color rgba="0 0 1.0 0.5" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <!-- 摄像头 -->
    <link name="camera">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.02 0.05 0.05" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="red">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 0.5" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <!-- 关节 -->
    <joint name="camera2baselink" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="camera" />
        <!-- 需要计算两个 link 的物理中心之间的偏移量 -->
        <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>

</robot>
```

launch文件

```xml
 <launch>

    <!-- 设置参数 -->
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find urdf01_rviz)/urdf/urdf/joint.urdf" />
<!-- 启动 rviz -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find urdf01_rviz)/config/1.rviz"/>
 <!-- 添加关节状态发布节点 -->
<node pkg="joint_state_publisher"type="joint_state_publisher"name="joint_state_publisher" />
 <!-- 添加机器人状态发布节点 -->
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher"type="robot_state_publisher"name="robot_state_publisher" />
</launch>
```

```
下面是运行rviz图片、、rostopic echo /joint_states、、rostopic echo /tf、、rosnode info /joint_state_publisher、、rosnode info /robot_state_publisher
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please ask your question in English ... do NOT include pictures of text ... add the text instead